# Section width below the header is not set 100%

Tags: html, css

I am facing a problem in case of mobile responsive. The section below the header width can't be 100%. I used width 100% !important, but not working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9XSB.png)

Comment: Use 100vw instead of 100%.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `width: 100vw;` instead of 100%.